# Citrus Simulator throws Nullpointer Exception when receiving serialized xml data

Tags: java, citrus-framework

I'm running Citrus Simulator as a spring-boot application to simulate web services responding to HTTP POST calls.
Everything works fine in "lab" conditions. As long as I send data by hand via Postman, curl, or a browser plugin I have no problems and clean answers. Once the data is sent by another application however, I get a nasty nullpointer exception.

It took me a while to pinpoint the issue but now I know it to be the format of the sent data.

**Sending pretty printed xml data results in a perfect answer. As soon as I serialize the xml though, it won't be processed by Citrus Simulator correctly and I'll get a nullpointer exception**.

Using curl I'm also able to provoke the error simply by killing the format of the sent xml file.

*Edit* It's not the format directly. Both applications, when sending data in a pretty printed format, will generate a HTTP Header Metadata with some (strange) contents -> curl sends Metadata="\t\t\t", postman sends Metadata="\n      ".
Sending a serialized xml, both applications send an empty Metadata Header thus resulting in a nullpointer exception 
right here `(MessageService.java:60) -> StringUtils.abbreviate(headerEntry.getValue().toString(), 255))));`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.consol.citrus.simulator.service.MessageService.lambda$saveMessage$0(MessageService.java:60) ~[citrus-simulator-starter-1.0.3.jar:na]
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
at com.consol.citrus.simulator.service.MessageService.saveMessage(MessageService.java:58) ~[citrus-simulator-starter-1.0.3.jar:na]
at com.consol.citrus.simulator.service.MessageService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$be0e8eaa.invoke(<generated>) ~[citrus-simulator-starter-1.0.3.jar:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736) ~[spring-aop-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671) ~[spring-aop-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at com.consol.citrus.simulator.service.MessageService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f26ac16e.saveMessage(<generated>) ~[citrus-simulator-starter-1.0.3.jar:na]
at com.consol.citrus.simulator.service.ActivityService.saveScenarioMessage(ActivityService.java:124) ~[citrus-simulator-starter-1.0.3.jar:na]
at com.consol.citrus.simulator.service.ActivityService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1784762a.invoke(<generated>) ~[citrus-simulator-starter-1.0.3.jar:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736) ~[spring-aop-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671) ~[spring-aop-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at com.consol.citrus.simulator.service.ActivityService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$35f927ee.saveScenarioMessage(<generated>) ~[citrus-simulator-starter-1.0.3.jar:na]
at com.consol.citrus.simulator.endpoint.EndpointMessageHandler.saveScenarioMessage(EndpointMessageHandler.java:58) ~[citrus-simulator-starter-1.0.3.jar:na]
at com.consol.citrus.simulator.endpoint.EndpointMessageHandler.handleReceivedMessage(EndpointMessageHandler.java:51) ~[citrus-simulator-starter-1.0.3.jar:na]
at com.consol.citrus.simulator.scenario.ScenarioEndpoint.messageReceived(ScenarioEndpoint.java:111) ~[citrus-simulator-starter-1.0.3.jar:na]
at com.consol.citrus.simulator.scenario.ScenarioEndpoint.receive(ScenarioEndpoint.java:88) ~[citrus-simulator-starter-1.0.3.jar:na]
at com.consol.citrus.simulator.scenario.SVManagerScenario.receive(SVManagerScenario.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
at com.consol.citrus.simulator.scenario.SVManagerScenario.run(SVManagerScenario.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:215) ~[spring-core-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at com.consol.citrus.simulator.service.ScenarioExecutionService.lambda$null$3(ScenarioExecutionService.java:150) ~[citrus-simulator-starter-1.0.3.jar:na]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:491) ~[spring-core-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
at com.consol.citrus.simulator.service.ScenarioExecutionService.lambda$startScenarioAsync$4(ScenarioExecutionService.java:111) ~[citrus-simulator-starter-1.0.3.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to get the latest builds of citrus. My setup is running on java 1.8 and citrus 2.7.1

Has anyone ever had a similar issue with an older version of Citrus Simulator?

I'm grateful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never investigated in the cause of this (well, it's some null-header obviously), but a simple workaround (*not solution!*) is to override the `com.consol.citrus.simulator.serviceMessageService` bean as following:

```java
@Service
@Primary
@Transactional
public class NullHeaderAwareMessageService extends MessageService {

    private final MessageRepository messageRepository;

    @Autowired
    public NullHeaderAwareMessageService(MessageRepository messageRepository) {
        super(messageRepository);

        this.messageRepository = messageRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Message saveMessage(Message.Direction direction, String payload, String citrusMessageId, Map<String, Object> headers) {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setDate(new Date());
        message.setDirection(direction);
        message.setPayload(payload);
        message.setCitrusMessageId(citrusMessageId);
        if (headers != null) {
            headers.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(headerEntry -> headerEntry.getValue() != null)
                    .forEach(headerEntry -> message.addHeader(
                                new MessageHeader(headerEntry.getKey(),
                                        StringUtils.abbreviate(headerEntry.getValue().toString(), 255))));
        }

        return messageRepository.save(message);
    }
}
```